# Best practice for biblatex, biber, utf8 files

Tags: biblatex, best-practices, biber, bibdesk

I use biblatex and biber. I used to use bibtex. So, when I first started writing .bib files I would have entries like this:

```
@article{descartes,
    Author = {Descartes, Ren{\'{e}}}
    Title = {`Something' --- Something}
}
```

Now I do this:

```
@article{descartes,
    Author = {Descartes, René}
    Title = {`Something' --- Something}
}
```

I use the unicode accented e, but I don't replace the single quotes or dash with unicode equivalents. This works fine, but it seems to me that I'm probably mixing two conventions for no reason. (I also use two hyphens rather than one for a page range, even though I know that I don't need to with biblatex.)

Is there any specific reason why it would be best practice to change to using unicode for everything, or any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: I would use `\enquote` for the quotes so that can be adapted in the document.

Comment: Or `\mkbibquote`, which handles the annoyances of the "American" rules for quotation marks and trailing punctuation. (I forget if `biblatex` will do that with `csquote`'s `\enquote` command.)

Comment: Or use 'active' quotes which avoid cluttering the source but have similar advantages. (I actually use the unicode curly quotes as active quotes for this purpose.)

Comment: You are not really mixing 2 conventions except superficially. Accented characters are one thing. Ligatures are another. At least for standard TeX/pdfTeX, `--` and `---` are ligatures in the same way that `fi` and `ffi` etc. are. So, even if consistency were a particular virtue here, you wouldn't need to replace `--` and `---` unless you also input the `fi` etc. ligatures directly. (And I don't know why you'd do that.) If you use XeTeX/LuaTeX, things might be a bit different....

Comment: @cfr I am using xetex as it happens. But I think that's a helpful point anyway.

Comment: @cfr I found a reference to active characters in the biblatex manual. I don't fully understand them though. Is there a simple explanation you can point to?

Comment: Look at the `csquotes` documentation. For example, I use `\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}` and then use `‘something’`.

Comment: I think it is sensible to enter UTF8 glyphs that can easily be produced with your keyboard directly (è, a, ß - of course that all depends on the keyboard layout, and portability might suffer) while characters that are harder to produce (en-dash, em-dash) (not knowing their UTF8 code point) can be entered with their macro. It's good to weigh a neat and easily readable picture in the file against ease of inoput. In some fonts or editors it might be quite hard to distinguish certain glyphs (e.g. `b-b–b—b`/b-b–b—b), in which case the macro greatly improves readability.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I'm going to write up an answer with all these helpful comments.

Comment: It is more customary and considered more polite to ask one of those who commented to write up an answer rather than taking the credit for the suggestions provided to you by other people. If several people have helped, you'd ask the one who made the most helpful points. (This is sometimes a bit arbitrary, of course.)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks. I'll delete my answer if anybody else writes one.

Comment: In this case, where there were many people contributing, you could answer yourself, but mark the answer community wiki and ask those wo commented to contribute.

Comment: I made it community wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no technical reason not to mix utf8 text and LaTeX in one .bib file. Biblatex, with biber, handles both fine. Ease of input, readability, and portability may count in favour of various approaches.

- For some fonts, especially fixed width ones, hyphens, en-dashes, and em-dashes are hard to distinguish.
- Some characters are hard to input, especially dashes. Others, depending on the keyboard, are easier.
- If the quotes are done as `, `'`, ``` `` ```, and `''` (i.e. LaTeX) then they won't adapt to the quote settings controlled by the document's language. Using `\enquote` allows them to be, but might be considered less readable. Using csquote.sty's active characters is a better solution e.g. `\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}`.

If you use BibDesk it's also worth thinking about exporting files. Using export templates it's possible to convert LaTeX or utf8 plain text to rich text. It's also possible to convert LaTeX dashes to unicode, but not vice versa. It's also not possible to convert LaTeX quotes to smart unicode quotes.